# Entity-framework 6.1 querystring and ObjectContext

Tags: entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6, dbcontext, httpcontext, objectcontext

I am new to Entity-framework and MVC and I am trying to make a Data Access Layer (separate layer). I am using VS 2013, Entity-framework 6.1.3 and MVC5. So far I have created Connection Helper class to connect to the database, but I need a little help here.

**IConnectionHelper.cs**

```
public interface IConnectionHelper
{
    string ConnectionString { get; }
    ObjectContext Connection { get; }
}
```

**ConnectionHelper.cs**

```
public class ConnectionHelper : IConnectionHelper
{
    public string ConnectionString
    {
        get {
            return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["databaseEntities"].ToString();
        }
    }

    private ObjectContext _connection;
    public ObjectContext Connection
    {
        get {
                //Need Help what to do here!
        }
    }
}
```

**I just want to learn how to pass connection string name to its constructor.**
Can you guys please help me, Thanks

Comment: Don't do this in a web application. An ObjectContext is meant to be created and destroyed after each use.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin: Ok, can you please suggest me what should I do? Your help is highly appreciable. Thanks

Comment: I can't answer that without more context as to what exactly you are building, but you can start here - https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: @EkoostikMartin Thanks for your comment, Actually I wanna learn how to make a separate data layer and use it in MVC5 web application. I am using C# class library to make the data layer, created ADO.net entity data model and now need help with ObjectContext in datahelper.cs

Comment: so there is no one, who Can help me?